# Prove the set $E = \left\{(x,y,z)\in\textbf{R}^{3}\mid\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} + \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} + \frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}} \leq 1\right\}$ is convex

Tags: real-analysis, conic-sections, inner-products, solution-verification

Prove that the ellipsoid
\begin{align*}
E = \left\{(x,y,z)\in\textbf{R}^{3}\mid\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}} + \frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}} + \frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}} \leq 1\right\}
\end{align*}

is convex.

**MY ATTEMPT**

To start with, let us consider the inner product defined by
\begin{align*}
\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\rangle = \frac{x_{1}y_{1}}{a^{2}} + \frac{x_{2}y_{2}}{b^{2}} + \frac{x_{3}y_{3}}{c^{2}}
\end{align*}

It is not hard to prove such function is bilinear, symmetric and positive-definite.

Thus $E$ is the unit ball accordingly to such inner product. Hence, if we take two points $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$ in $E$, its convex combination also belongs to $E$. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
\langle t\textbf{x} + (1-t)\textbf{y},t\textbf{x} + (1-t)\textbf{y}\rangle & = t^{2}\|\textbf{x}\|^{2} + 2t(1-t)\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\rangle + (1-t)^{2}\|\textbf{y}\|^{2}\\\\
& \leq t^{2}\|\textbf{x}\|^{2} + 2t(1-t)|\langle\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\rangle| + (1-t)^{2}\|\textbf{y}\|^{2}\\\\
& \leq t^{2}\|\textbf{x}\|^{2} + 2t(1-t)\|\textbf{x}\|\|\textbf{y}\| + (1-t)^{2}\|\textbf{y}\|^{2}\\\\
& \leq t^{2} + 2t(1-t) + (1-t)^{2} = 1
\end{align*}

Could someone double-check my solution? Any comment is welcome.

Comment: This is correct and can also easily be generalized to $n$ dimensions. The nice thing about your proof is that your ellipse becomes a circle with respect to your inner product

Comment: A variant on the same idea: (1) It's easy to see that a standard Euclidean ball is convex, (2) $E$ is the image of the unit ball under a *linear* transformation, so is also convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative approach using norm:

Let $A=\operatorname{diag}(\frac1{a}, \frac1{b}, \frac1{c})$.

If $x^TA^2x=\|Ax\|^2 \le 1 $ and $y^TA^2y=\|Ay\|^2 \le 1 $ $\iff \|Ax\| \le 1$  and $\|Ay\|\le1$,

Let $t \in (0,1)$, 
$$\|A(tx+(1-t)y)\| \le t\|Ax\| + (1-t) \|Ay\| \le t + (1-t)=1$$

where I have used the triangle inequality.

Comment: ah yes, thanks.